# How to communicate my server using GSM modem ip address in java?

Tags: java, serial-port, ip-address, gsm

I am using sim900 gsm model for my server to connect from gprs network. My server is connected to lan. I want to connect my server from ethernet and gprs. I have installed this server in phytech board with arch linux os and gsm model is connected through serial port ie, /dev/ttyO0.I searched lot on this but got only AT command communication and that i can able to do. My question is, i should be able to communicate my server by client using either lan or gprs or how can i assign gsm modem ip address to my server? I need any steps or piece of code for this, where i can understand. Any help will be appreciated.